# How to change starts image of rating bar in android

Tags: android, image, rating-system

How can I change the starts image in the android rating bar?

I need it to show it to the user.

Or if not possible - how can show X images of start in a specific possition in the layout?

Yoav

Comment: what do you mean by the android rating bar?

Comment: Show ratig as starts - like any site (imdb etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hope I understod your question - you want to use RatingBar and set custom images?

Android's `RatingBar` already displays stars, but if you want custom image then Define a [custom style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

```
<style name="customRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_image</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/custom_image</item>
</style>
```

And then use it

```
<RatingBar style="@style/customRatingBar" ... />
```

Comment: This doesn't work with vector drawables

Answer (score 0):

First create one drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"

        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" />
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

then use drawable in rating bar attribute   `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_rating_stars"'

```
 <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:isIndicator="false"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/drawable_rating_stars"
                    android:scaleX="1"
                    android:scaleY="1"
                    android:stepSize="1.0" />
```